# Negative pattern match

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have the following code (`IgnoreCase is an active pattern I have defined elsewhere):

```
match myType with
| {Field1 = IgnoreCase "invalid"} -> None
| {Field2 = Some f2
   Field3 = Some f3
   Field4 = None | Some (0 | 1 | 2)}
    -> Some (f2, f3)
| _ -> None
```

As you can see, `Field1` has a blacklisted value and `Field4` has whitelisted values (so do `Field2` and `Field3` in the sense that they must be `Some`). IMHO it would look slightly cleaner if I could do all checks in the same case, i.e. do the `Field1 = IgnoreCase "invalid"` match together with the other matches using e.g. `Field1 <> IgnoreCase "invalid"`, but that particular example does not compile. I know about guards, but that does not seem cleaner than the original solution.

Is it possible to do "negative" (logical NOT) pattern matches in the sense that a value should not match some other value, without using guards?

Comment: You could add a guard: `{Field1 = f} when f <> "invalid"`.

Comment: Thanks. I know about guards and intended to mention that in the question. Updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no good way to do this.  You can see the supported patterns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) and verify that there's no construct for negation.  One reason for the lack of such a feature might be that it would interact strangely with other pattern matching features (e.g. what would it mean to introduce an identifier with an `as` pattern inside of a negative context?).  And this is not something that you could implement in a general fashion yourself via an active pattern, because an active pattern receives a value, not a pattern expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could define an active pattern called `Not`:

```
let (|Not|_|) a b = if a <> b then Some () else None
```

Then you can use it inside the pattern match:

```
match myType with
| {Field1 = Not "invalid"
   Field2 = Some f2
   Field3 = Some f3
   Field4 = None | Some (0 | 1 | 2)}
   -> Some (f2, f3)
| _ -> None
```

A limitation of this active pattern is that it must take a literal value, not a sub-pattern. Active patterns aren't composable like the built-in patterns. However, that's also a potential advantage because you can pass it identifiers as values instead of binding a new value to the identifier:

```
let invalidString = "invalid"

match myType with
| {Field1 = Not invalidString
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that before posting and, as you say, it does not work with sub-patterns. Unfortunately sub-patterns are needed in my case, but I didn't think to include it in the question. I have updated the question now to clarify this.

Comment: @cmeeren Well you could have another active pattern: `let (|ToLower|) x = (x:string).ToLower()` and then do `ToLower (Not "invalid")`, but it's getting silly now... I think you're trying to do too much with pattern matching. Use a guard or one specialised active pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use active patterns like this

```
let (|Check|_|) x =
    let = { Field2 = f2; Field3 = f3; Field4 = f4 }
    let check = 
        f4 = None ||
        f4 = Some 1 ||
        f4 = Some 2 ||
        f4 = Some 3
    if check then Some (f2, f3) else None

    match myType with
    | {Field1 = "invalid"} -> None
    | Check (x, y) -> Some (x, y)
    | _ -> None
```